# OcppV1.5 over Soap Error: Action does not exist

Tags: c#, http, soap, https, protocols

i am currently building a Client to communicate with a Gateway of a Charge Point.
The communication is build with OcppV1.5 over Soap & Http.
The Server  doesn't accept my request. I get a Http Response 500 with the Error Reason:

> "XML Request is not well formed, Action does not exist."

I looked into the wsdl files but I just don't understand why it doesn't accept my action.

My Request looks something like this:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="https://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:cs="urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/06/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <cs:chargeBoxIdentity>0000.0000</cs:chargeBoxIdentity>
    <wsa:From>
      <wsa:Address>http://000.000.000.000:0000</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:From>
    <wsa:To>http://000.000.000.001:0001</wsa:To>
    <wsa:Action>/ChangeConfiguration</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>00000.000000000000</wsa:MessageID>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <cs:changeConfigurationRequest>
      <cs:key>MeterValueSampleInterval</cs:key>
      <cs:value>60</cs:value>
    </cs:changeConfigurationRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

### Update:

As Bogdan suggested I tried to send the same message using SoapUi and it worked. The generated Request from SoapUi looks like this:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/06/">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <ns:chargeBoxIdentity>000000.00000</ns:chargeBoxIdentity>
      <wsa:Action>/ChangeConfiguration</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:ReplyTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://000.000.000.000:0000</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:MessageID>uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:To>http://000.000.000.000:00000/</wsa:To>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:changeConfigurationRequest>
         <ns:key>MeterValueSampleInterval</ns:key>
         <ns:value>300</ns:value>
      </ns:changeConfigurationRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you sure the SOAP request is properly formatted? Also, the message says "Action". Do you have an action parameter in your content type? https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3902.txt

Comment: No, I am not completely sure, that's why I am looking for help. I don't understand what you mean with content-type. But I am defining the Action as "/ChangeConfiguration", which is defined in the namespace "urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/06/", which is defined in the request. So the server should be able to understand the action, but for some reason it doesn't... The requests I got from the server (different Action type), I am trying to send to, were build the same way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from what you posted why you are getting an error, so I can only add some information that can hopefully allow you to troubleshoot the issue.

Your message has [WS-Addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Addressing) headers, `<wsa:Action>` being one of them. The value of this field should be specified in the WSDL if your WSDL also includes [WS-Addressing Metadata](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-ws-addr-metadata-20070904/#actioninwsdl) information, or should be specified in the documentation of the web service you are invoking. Your error message *"XML Request is not well formed, Action does not exist"* seems to indicate that there might be an issue with this field, but there is another action that SOAP services have which is a SOAP action. I asked about it in the comment above to make sure it's eliminated as a source of problems. In SOAP 1.1 it's called `SOAPAction` and is a separate HTTP header, while in SOAP 1.2 it's an [`action` parameter](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3902.txt) on the HTTP `Content-Type` header. Based on the `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` namespace, you have a SOAP 1.2 message.

With these explanations layed out, I suggest you take the WSDL and feed it to [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/) who can generate sample requests that you can use to invoke the web service. If the WSDL also contains WS-Addressing Metadata, SoapUI should be able to [pick it up](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/supported-standards/using-ws-addressing/) and help you fill in the values you need. If not, look again through the WSDL for `Action` elements (make sure you differentiate between the SOAP Action and the WS-Addressing Action using their XML namespaces) or through the service documentation.

Once you get a succesfull call using SoapUI, then try to duplicate it with your code. At that point you can again use SoapUI to troubleshoot things and [inspect your code built message](https://www.soapui.org/docs/http-recording/reference/http-monitor/) to see it resembles the one you can successfully send with SoapUI.

Hope this helps get you closer to a resolution.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. The tool SoapUi really was a great help solving the problem. :D